# Can't mark seams and other strange things

Tags: uv, edit-mode

I have a model of a lighthouse.
When I select a material for the roof as soon as I click on the 'ball' next to Base Color and select image texture, before I even select a texture image the roof goes black - that is the first thing I noticed which is different and may have a reason.
I then select the texture image and the roof is 'painted' with the image selected as expected.
I then go to Edit mode and notice that the edges and vertices are colored black when I expected them to be yellow.
I then press Ctrl - E and select mark seam - the edges and vertices do not change to red as expected suggesting they have not been marked.
I press U twice to unwrap and go to UV editing. The faces are not displayed.
What have I done wrong?
I have attached the blender file which does not have any materials so please use whatever you have as that is not the issue.

[image]

Comment: It looks like you forgot to select or something like that

Comment: I select the roof and it is highlighted suggesting that it was selected. I am sure I am doing exactly what I have been doing for months to uv unwrap etc.

Comment: It sounds as if you don't actually have any edges or verts selected when you're trying to mark the seams. The edges won't be marked unless they are selected (yellow) but you say that they are black which means they are not selected. You also have to select everything ('A' in Edit mode) before unwrapping or nothing will happen.

Comment: Thanks John. That is the answer. Strange that in the 18 months since using Blender I have never needed to do that (select all in edit mode). I have never used select all in edit mode only in object mode. Whenever I have applied a material and then did an unwrap I have never done or needed to do that before. Also I have never seen a mesh get 'painted' black when selecting a texture image to apply before either.